# adding vertices in a mesh

Tags: vertices, wireframe, subsurface-scattering

so i am a beginner to 3d modelling and am using blender. i want to add vertices inside a cup and i dont know how to do that. further steps include making the liquid inside the cup. need help. [image] a wireframed and xray viewport of the cup
[image]solid view mode the cup
[image]total wireframe viewport of the cup.

Comment: Suggest you watch Blender Guru's Donut tutorial starting from Part 2 Level 3 [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7a0cHFs7jkw).

Comment: thats what i did, but i know i did not miss any step but stillmaybe due to different versions, he has those vertices available and i dont.

Comment: He's using version 2.83 of Blender for the course whereas you're on 2.92 but the only real difference is how you actually apply the modifier. In the next video he actually applies the modifier at around 1.5 minutes in and then you will see the vertices appear on the inside of the cup. To apply a modifier in 2.93 click the little down arrow to the right of the camera icon in the modifier panel and click 'Apply' (in Object mode). You can also click in th modifier panel to select it (blue outline round it) and with the cursor over the panel, use CTRL-A to apply it.

Comment: thanks alot for your help. this modifier concept is still a bit confusing to me. really appreciate it :)

Comment: No problem. One thing he does mention is that you should apply the modifier before you start creating the cup handle, so if you get a strange artifact on the inside of the cup that's probably the reason. One tip: When I was following tutorials I always used to save my file under a different name at the end of each video. That way you don't have to start again from scratch if you make a serious error.